# Date-Time validation in Jquery for today

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have simple validators for my form in Jquery, 
and I would like to add validation rule that the date can't be before today. 
How do I write this?

My form validations rules:

```
$(document)
.ready(function() {
 $('.ui.form')
   .form({
     fields: {
       name: {
         identifier  : 'name',
         rules: [
           {
             type   : 'empty',
             prompt : 'Please enter event name'
           }
         ]
       },
       details: {
         identifier  : 'details',
         rules: [
           {
             type   : 'empty',
             prompt : 'Please enter details'
           }
         ]
       },
       date: {
         identifier  : 'date',
         rules: [
           {
             type   : 'empty',
             prompt : 'Please enter date'
           }
         ]
       }
     }
   })
  ;
 })
;
```

My date-time input in HTML:

```
 <div class="field">
    <div class="ui input">
      <i class="calendar icon"></i>
      <input type="datetime-local" name="date" placeholder="Date">
    </div>
 </div>
```

And I would like to add a rule for the date.

Can any one help my please? ;)

Comment: `<input type="datetime-local" name="date" min="2017-12-12T08:30" required>`

Comment: min="2017-12-12T08:30"
is for a static date. I need to use today, that changes every day...

Comment: Change it using jQuery when page is ready